# Android - the connection between foregroundservice and repository in mvvm

Tags: java, android, mvvm

I have my TransActionsRepository class that conrains method of insert, delete, getall that have access to database. I am using foregroundservice that I need to get access to database into the foregroundservice class, but I can't seem to find a way to make an instance of TransActionsRepository inside foregroundservice so I can use it's method to access the database.

Any idea on how to do that?
keep in mind I am using MVVM architecture